# In a vimrc, how do you preload a register with a string containing Special characters, like a newline?

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, gvim, vim-windows

In a **vimrc file** I want to **preload register C with a string** I regularly need when coding. The **string has a newline** in it but no success in getting it to work properly.

Here is an example **vimrc snippet** of one of my attempts:

```
" Powershell block comment preload
let @c="<# Start COMMENT `n # End COMMENT #>"
```

in addition to '`n', I have tried `r`n, <CR>, maybe some others.

How do I represent a newline character in a 'let' statement string in vimrc, and have it work like a newline/CR when called upon to be inserted into the code (essentially **inserted as a multi-line string**)?

For that matter, in general, how do I represent any special character in a set/let statement string in a vimrc, and have it operate as intended when you ask for the value of that register?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `\n` inside a double quoted string for a new line.

See [`:help expr-quote`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#expr-quote) for more details of the special sequences available inside a double quoted string. The special sequences inside double quoted strings start with a backslash.

In your specific example, this should do:

```
" Powershell block comment preload
let @c = "<# Start COMMENT \n # End COMMENT #>"
```

You might want to adjust spacing before/after the newline, to prevent leading/trailing spaces as necessary.

Comment: Who would have thought the vim help key word was 'expr-quote' to get this info...not to mention searching online using keywords like vimrc, newline, statement strings, special characters would yield no results.